# center points of Python3 floating points with print

Tags: python-3.x

How can I print floating point numbers in Python3 line by line centered by their `.`?

```
>>> print('{:6}\n{:6}'.format(2, 46))
     2
    46
>>> print('{:.2f}\n{:.2f}'.format(2.34985, 82.23132))
2.35
82.23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same way you do for integers.

```
print('{:6.2f}\n{:6.2f}'.format(2.34985, 82.23132))
  2.35
 82.23
```